# Login screen freezes

Tags: 16.04, login, startup, 16.10

I have upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10 and when it reboots it starts normal but once at log in it freezes. Can't use keyboard or mouse. Please help! 
To see what I'm really talking about... I made a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g0TID-rJ8w&feature=share

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of [this problem](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2050999). The user here recommended booting from recovery and running the following as root:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

In addition, if this is a login issue it could be an issue with lightdm. To reconfigure and restart lightdm, type Ctrl+Alt+F1 to move into a terminal, login, and type

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
sudo service lightdm restart
```

to get back from terminal, type Ctrl+Alt+F7

Comment: Didn't work. I rebooted into recovery and selected root. Typed in what you said, nothing will work. And I can't access terminal in login.